# Validate max file input size with Parsley.js?

Tags: forms, validation, parsley.js

I have searched and searched for a solution to this, but still haven't found an answer to solve my problem.

I have this form with multiple file input fields, that let's the user upload images.

First of all, these fields are not mandatory, so they might be empty.

Problem is, I can't find a way to validate these fields with the help of Parsley. I would like Parsley to check if the file is larger than the allowed size (1.5 MB), either on form submit or when the image is chosen in the file input field.

Since I haven't been able to find any documentation on this, I don't have a code to start with at the moment, only a normal form.

Oh, and yes: Parsley does validate the other fields that are mandatory in my form.

Comment: If you're using Parsley 1.*, there's a [solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26035399/908174). I've yet to come up with a solution for 2.*

Comment: Thanks @milz , I'm using Parsley 2 unfortunately. Maybe I could switch, have to think about that. :)

Comment: Hope youre still interested: The problem of the solution of 1.* seems to be that the 3rd argument of the callback-function which represents the DOM is not supported anymore. Is there an other way to get it?